# RAD Embedded Derby database inside my project folder how to connect to database path

Tags: database, connection, derby, rad

I am using Derby embbeded database in My RAD IDE. I have created a Database inside my project folder and connected to it by

Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:I:\Java Programs\EAppointment\WebContent\Eappointment;create=true;user=subbu;password=");

but when i send the ear file to my superior. It is not running. Database path error occurs.

Can anyone suggest me how to overcome the error.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a problem with backslashes in Java strings. You're probably not getting
the Windows path separator, but rather getting the characters \J, \E, \W, and \E
embedded into your string.

So you'd have to double the backslashes, or change them to forward slashes.

And the spaces in the directory name are going to be annoying, too, so it's
easier to avoid them.

Try starting by making a database at the root level of your "I:" drive, as in:

"jdbc:derby:I:/Eappointment;create=true;user=subbu;password="

Then once you get the basic syntax working, you can work on techniques
for more advanced control of your database location.

Comment: But the same works in my system. But when is send the EAR file. and use the same ear file in my superior system. the error occurs.